# Django - How to display Scientific Notation on Admin Page Field?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-forms

I have a field in my admin page that I'd like to display in Scientific Notation.

Right now it displays something ugly like this.  How can I display this as 4.08E+13?

[image]

Right now I'm using a standard Decimal field in the model.

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

I'm on Django 1.2.

Comment: I'm thinking I need to make a custom model field that uses a custom form field.  Is that correct, or is it impossible what I'm trying to do?  (I know the admin is limited in some cases).

Comment: I'm not seeing much action on this thread.  I might go hit up the Django IRC and report back.

Comment: I'm not seeing much action on the Django users group either.

Comment: IRC seems to be down.  No luck there either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, here's a work around since I can't figure out how to do this within the Django Python code.  I have the admin pages run some custom javascript to do the conversion after the page is loaded.

**Details:**

Create this javascript file called "decimal_to_sci_not.js" and place it in your media directory:

```
/*
Finds and converts decimal fields > N into scientific notation.
*/

THRESHOLD = 100000;
PRECISION = 3;

function convert(val) {
    // ex. 100000 -> 1.00e+5
    return parseFloat(val).toPrecision(PRECISION);
}

function convert_input_fields() {
    var f_inputs = django.jQuery('input');
    f_inputs.each(function (index, domEl) {
        var jEl = django.jQuery(this);
        var old_val = parseFloat(jEl.val());
        if (old_val >= THRESHOLD) {
           jEl.val(convert(old_val));
        }
    });
}

function convert_table_cells() {
    //Look through all td elements and replace the first n.n number found inside
    //if greater than or equal to THRESHOLD
    var cells = django.jQuery('td');
    var re_num = /\d+\.\d+/m; //match any numbers w decimal
    cells.each(function (index, domEl) {
        var jEl = django.jQuery(this);
        var old_val_str = jEl.html().match(re_num);
        var old_val = parseFloat(old_val_str);
        if (old_val >= THRESHOLD) {
           jEl.html(jEl.html().replace(old_val_str,convert(old_val)));
        }
    });
}

django.jQuery(document).ready( function () {
    convert_input_fields();
    convert_table_cells();
});
```

Then update your admin.py code classes to include the javascript file:

```
class MyModel1Admin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    class Media:
        js = ['/media/decimal_to_sci_not.js']

admin.site.register(MyModel1,MyModel1Admin)
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to use `%e` to get the scientific notation format:

### Basic Example:

```python
x = 374.534  
print("%e" % x)
# 3.745340e+02
```

### Precision of 2

```python
x = 374.534
print("{0:.2E}".format(x))
# 3.75E+02

x = 12345678901234567890.534
print("{0:.2E}".format(x))
# 1.23E+19
```

### Precision of 3

```python
print("{0:.3E}".format(x))
# 1.235E+19
```

Comment: Can you expand on this?  Perhaps explain where this should be done?  Perhaps show how the form would use this formatting string?

Comment: Yeah, as S.Lott said, I'm asking more about the Django part of this solution instead of just the python part.

Comment: First of all, sorry about the bad link :| Too much windows opened makes people act (and post) like crazy. As far as i know, django uses Decimal datatype from python's libraries, to convert the opposite (from scientific to decimal numbers). What i answered is the formatting of the number, like string formatting (with %s), float numbers (with %f). You can store it in a variable any time (ex, num = 10, test = '%e' % num, print test... try this for yourself). If you want to use it as fieldtype value, just inject the converted value into the form and voilat!