# Display a decimal in scientific notation

Tags: python, string-formatting, number-formatting, scientific-notation

How can I display `Decimal('40800000000.00000000000000')` as `'4.08E+10'`?

I've tried this:

```
>>> '%E' % Decimal('40800000000.00000000000000')
'4.080000E+10'
```

But it has those extra 0's.

Comment: kinda doubleposting, you could have used this topic you just started: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913166/django-how-to-display-scientific-notation-on-admin-page-field

Comment: nah, not at all. I wanted to separate this into the easy question (how to do it in Python) and the hard, obscure question that I doubt anyone will answer (how to do it in Django).  Notice how this already has an answer.  I'm now halfway to my final answer instead of 0% if I had posted them together.  Besides that, separating the questions makes it easier for people to search for the answers.  E.,g if Bob is searching for a decimal formatting question he might skip a SO questin with Django in the title.

Answer (score 229, accepted):

```
from decimal import Decimal

'%.2E' % Decimal('40800000000.00000000000000')

# returns '4.08E+10'
```

In your '40800000000.00000000000000' there are many more significant zeros that have the same meaning as any other digit. That's why you have to tell explicitly where you want to stop.

If you want to remove all trailing zeros automatically, you can try:

```
def format_e(n):
    a = '%E' % n
    return a.split('E')[0].rstrip('0').rstrip('.') + 'E' + a.split('E')[1]

format_e(Decimal('40800000000.00000000000000'))
# '4.08E+10'

format_e(Decimal('40000000000.00000000000000'))
# '4E+10'

format_e(Decimal('40812300000.00000000000000'))
# '4.08123E+10'
```

Comment: As an aside, despite the `format % values` syntax still being used even within the Python 3 standard library, I believe it's technically deprecated in Python 3, or at least not the recommended formatting method, and the current recommended syntax, starting with Python 2.6, would be `'{0:.2E}'.format(Decimal('40800000000.00000000000000'))` (or `'{:.2E}'` in Python 2.7+). While not strictly useful for this situation, due to the additional characters for no added functionality, `str.format` does allow for more complex mixing/rearranging/reutilizing of format arguments.

Comment: @CharlieParker Use [`format`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19864272/365102). It's more *jazzy*.

Answer (score 185):

Here's an example using the `format()` function:

```
>>> "{:.2E}".format(Decimal('40800000000.00000000000000'))
'4.08E+10'
```

Instead of format, you can also use [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew36-pep498):

```
>>> f"{Decimal('40800000000.00000000000000'):.2E}"
'4.08E+10'
```

- [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/string.html#formatspec)
- [original format() proposal](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/)

Comment: This syntax also applies to f-strings in 3.6+ `f"{Decimal('40800000000.00000000000000'):.2E}"`

Answer (score 73):

Given your number

```
x = Decimal('40800000000.00000000000000')
```

Starting from Python 3,

```
'{:.2e}'.format(x)
```

is the recommended way to do it.

`e` means you want scientific notation, and `.2` means you want 2 digits after the dot. So you will get `x.xxE±n`

Comment: The point of using Decimal is to get exact and arbitrary precision decimal arithmetic. It is not equivalent to using a float.

Comment: @asmeurer Thanks for the clarification. Changed my answer.

Comment: Is there a way to get back from this to float?

Comment: @olenscki just doing `float(x)` will convert x into float.

Comment: Is there a difference between `e` and `E` ?

Comment: I don't think so, no.

Comment: @minseong: from the [documentation:](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings) "*Scientific notation. Same as 'e' except it uses an upper case ‘E’ as the separator character*"

Answer (score 49):

No one mentioned the short form of the `.format` method:

**Needs at least Python 3.6**

```
f"{Decimal('40800000000.00000000000000'):.2E}"
```

(I believe it's the same as Cees Timmerman, just a bit shorter)

Comment: Should be accepted answer. f-strings is the future of python string formatting :)

Comment: As an fyi to future readers like myself: if you don't care to control the number of digits and don't mind floating point errors, you can simply use `{num:E}`, where e.g. num = 40800000000.00000000000000

Comment: For information about formatting https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45310254/fixed-digits-after-decimal-with-f-strings#45310389

Comment: Following on from shayaan's recommendation that is f"{num:E}"

Answer (score 19):

This is a consolidated list of the *"Simple"* Answers & Comments.

## PYTHON 3

```
from decimal import Decimal

x = '40800000000.00000000000000'
# Converted to Float
x = Decimal(x)

# ===================================== # `Dot Format`
print("{0:.2E}".format(x))
# ===================================== # `%` Format
print("%.2E" % x)
# ===================================== # `f` Format
print(f"{x:.2E}")
# =====================================
# ALL Return: 4.08E+10
print((f"{x:.2E}") == ("%.2E" % x) == ("{0:.2E}".format(x)))
# True
print(type(f"{x:.2E}") == type("%.2E" % x) == type("{0:.2E}".format(x)))
# True
# =====================================
```

## OR Without `IMPORT`'s

```
# NO IMPORT NEEDED FOR BASIC FLOATS
y = '40800000000.00000000000000'
y = float(y)

# ===================================== # `Dot Format`
print("{0:.2E}".format(y))
# ===================================== # `%` Format
print("%.2E" % y)
# ===================================== # `f` Format
print(f"{y:.2E}")
# =====================================
# ALL Return: 4.08E+10
print((f"{y:.2E}") == ("%.2E" % y) == ("{0:.2E}".format(y)))
# True
print(type(f"{y:.2E}") == type("%.2E" % y) == type("{0:.2E}".format(y)))
# True
# =====================================
```

## Comparing

```
# =====================================
x
# Decimal('40800000000.00000000000000')
y
# 40800000000.0

type(x)
# <class 'decimal.Decimal'>
type(y)
# <class 'float'>

x == y
# True
type(x) == type(y)
# False

x
# Decimal('40800000000.00000000000000')
y
# 40800000000.0
```

So for Python 3, you can switch between any of the three for now.

My Fav:

```
print("{0:.2E}".format(y))
```

Comment: Example Usage: https://github.com/JayRizzo/rg_code/blob/master/class_act/factions.py#L37

Answer (score 12):

See tables from [Python string formatting](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting) to select the proper format layout. In your case it's `%.2E`.

Answer (score 5):

This worked best for me:

```
import decimal
'%.2E' % decimal.Decimal('40800000000.00000000000000')
# 4.08E+10
```

Answer (score 4):

My decimals are too big for `%E` so I had to improvize:

```
def format_decimal(x, prec=2):
    tup = x.as_tuple()
    digits = list(tup.digits[:prec + 1])
    sign = '-' if tup.sign else ''
    dec = ''.join(str(i) for i in digits[1:])
    exp = x.adjusted()
    return '{sign}{int}.{dec}e{exp}'.format(sign=sign, int=digits[0], dec=dec, exp=exp)
```

Here's an example usage:

```
>>> n = decimal.Decimal(4.3) ** 12314
>>> print format_decimal(n)
3.39e7800
>>> print '%e' % n
inf
```

Comment: Just `"{:.2e}".format(n)` returns `'3.39e+7800'` in Python 3.3.2 (v3.3.2:d047928ae3f6, May 16 2013, 00:06:53) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32.

Answer (score 4):

To convert a Decimal to scientific notation without needing to specify the precision in the format string, and without including trailing zeros, I'm currently using

```
def sci_str(dec):
    return ('{:.' + str(len(dec.normalize().as_tuple().digits) - 1) + 'E}').format(dec)

print( sci_str( Decimal('123.456000') ) )    # 1.23456E+2
```

To keep any trailing zeros, just remove the `normalize()`.

Answer (score 4):

I prefer Python 3.x way.

```
cal = 123.4567
print(f"result {cal:.4E}")
```

`4` indicates how many digits are shown shown in the floating part.

```
cal = 123.4567
totalDigitInFloatingPArt = 4
print(f"result {cal:.{totalDigitInFloatingPArt}E} ")
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding an updated answer to show how to apply `e notation` to small numbers only

```
value = 0.1
a = "{:,}".format(value) if value >= 0.001 else "{:,.3e}".format(value)
print(a) # 0.1

value = 0.00002488
a = "{:,}".format(value) if value >= 0.001 else "{:,.3e}".format(value)
print(a) # 2.488e-05
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the simplest one I could find.

```
format(40800000000.00000000000000, '.2E')
#'4.08E+10'
```

('E' is not case sensitive. You can also use '.2e')

Answer (score 0):

```
def formatE_decimal(x, prec=2):
    """ Examples:
    >>> formatE_decimal('0.1613965',10)
    '1.6139650000E-01'
    >>> formatE_decimal('0.1613965',5)
    '1.61397E-01'
    >>> formatE_decimal('0.9995',2)
    '1.00E+00'
    """
    xx=decimal.Decimal(x) if type(x)==type("") else x 
    tup = xx.as_tuple()
    xx=xx.quantize( decimal.Decimal("1E{0}".format(len(tup[1])+tup[2]-prec-1)), decimal.ROUND_HALF_UP )
    tup = xx.as_tuple()
    exp = xx.adjusted()
    sign = '-' if tup.sign else ''
    dec = ''.join(str(i) for i in tup[1][1:prec+1])   
    if prec>0:
        return '{sign}{int}.{dec}E{exp:+03d}'.format(sign=sign, int=tup[1][0], dec=dec, exp=exp)
    elif prec==0:
        return '{sign}{int}E{exp:+03d}'.format(sign=sign, int=tup[1][0], exp=exp)
    else:
        return None
```