# Out put format should be according to scientific notation

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

In my program I am calculating large number of values and I want to write the calculated values according to scientific notation as an example it should be as follow.

```
0.16200000000    should be   1.6200000000e-01
6.09756097560    should be   6.0975609756e+00
```

Which function results this out put.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python - How to convert decimal to scientific notation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913532/python-how-to-convert-decimal-to-scientific-notation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'%.10e' % (your value)

This is the easiest way to convert in to scientific notation.

Answer (score 2):

`'%e' % (number)`

The %e format specifier is the specifier for scientific notations. Find out more here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html