# How to print very large natural numbers in Python in non exponential form?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The number can be very large

```
n = input()
print(n) #gives output in scientific notation
```

How to get the entire number?

PS: New to python

EDIT:

```
s = (input())      #100000000000000000000000000000000000000
if int(s[-1])%2 == 0:
    print (2)
    print (2)
    print (int(s)/2)         #5e+37
```

Comment: The question is unclear. Give an example of what "input" looks like and what the printout should look like

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python 3, if you want integer division, use the `//` operator:

```
print(int(s) // 2)
```

The result of the division will be an integer and will not get printed out in the scientific notation.

Comment: Note that `//` operator has been there [*since Python 2.2*](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/2.2.html#pep-238-changing-the-division-operator). So it is the recommended way to obtain integer division since then (even on python2). Your wording may be interpreted as if `//` is only part of python3, and one should use `/` in python2.

Answer (score 1):

You can format a large number into a scientific notation using the `{:2E}` formatting code. Example:

```
>>> "{:.2E}".format(100000000000000000000000000000000000000)
'1.00E+38'
```

Another variation to do this:

```
>>> n = 100000000000000000000000000000000000000
>>> '%2E' % n
'1.000000E+38'
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913532/python-how-to-convert-decimal-to-scientific-notation) for discussion about the stripping out the extra zeros from the output.