# Code shows results when run interactively, but not when run from a shell

Tags: python, console

I borrowed this little scientific notation script from another poster: [Display a decimal in scientific notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913532/python-how-to-convert-decimal-to-scientific-notation]).

```
def format_e(n):
    a = '%E' % n
    return a.split('E')[0].rstrip('0').rstrip('.') + 'E' + a.split('E')[1]

format_e(Decimal('40800000000.00000000000000'))
# '4.08E+10'

format_e(Decimal('40000000000.00000000000000'))
# '4E+10'

format_e(Decimal('40812300000.00000000000000'))
```

The function works fine when manipulated as module from the Terminal or the Python Shell. However, when ran like 'python Converter.py' it terminates immediately without returning any of the three examples above.

Comment: Note the problem description in the updated title.. so, what is special about running interactively?

Comment: Probably nothing, I use gedit then run from the command line 99% of the time. Sleep deprivation has some special effects, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The interactive interpreter auto-echoes the results of any expression that doesn't return `None`. In a script you need to explicitly *print* the results you want to see:

```
print format_e(Decimal('40800000000.00000000000000'))
print format_e(Decimal('40000000000.00000000000000'))
print format_e(Decimal('40812300000.00000000000000'))
```

Comment: Thank you! That was a really silly question, but I didn't remember that detail.