# How change a number to Scientific Number and get the minimum value (Scientific Number format)

Tags: python, linux, perl, sorting, awk

How change a number to scientific number in linux?

Number

```
0.000111309
```

scientific number

```
1.11E-04
```

Used awk,python or perl. Thanks.

And, how to get the minimum value from many Scientific Number in python? Just like `sort -g | sed -n '$p'` in bash.

whether python can change automatically number to Scientific Number when print? 
 I'm find the 0 will become to 0.000000e+00 when print.

Comment: This can be be done by string formatting as explained in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913532/display-a-decimal-in-scientific-notation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need scientific notation you need to use the `%e` or `%E` format specifier

Using [awk](/questions/tagged/awk)

```
awk 'BEGIN{printf("%.2E\n",0.000111309)}'
1.11E-04
```

Using [python](/questions/tagged/python)

```
akshay@db-3325:~$ python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import decimal
>>> '%.2E' % decimal.Decimal('0.000111309')
'1.11E-04'
>>>
```

Using [perl](/questions/tagged/perl)

```
akshay@db-3325:~$ perl -e 'printf("%.2E\n",0.000111309)'
1.11E-04
```

Using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)

```
akshay@db-3325:~$ printf "%.2E\n" 0.000111309
1.11E-04
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print "%.4g" % 80085
```

Will output:

```
8.008e+04
```

Comment: `%g` and `%G` are simplifiers of the scientific notation floats `%e` and `%E`

Answer (score 0):

bash can do it as well

```
$ printf "%E\n" 0.000111309
1.113090E-04
```

with rounding to two decimal digits

```
$ printf "%.2E\n" 0.000111309
1.11E-04
```