# What is this data format? and how to convert from numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

I tried to do a pattern recognition assignment using this data format in txtfile.

**3.700000000000000000e+01**

But i only managed to wrote this.

```
import numpy
import PIL

# Convert Image to array
img = PIL.Image.open("imagefilename.png").convert("L")
arr = numpy.array(img)
```

and the output i get in array is this.

```
[[ 85  85  86 ..., 194 196 194]
 [ 84  84  85 ..., 194 196 194]
 [ 84  85  86 ..., 193 195 195]
 ..., 
 [177 177 177 ..., 162 162 162]
 [174 174 173 ..., 163 163 163]
 [  1   1   1 ...,   0   0   0]]
```

so my question is what is this format? 
**3.700000000000000000e+01**
which follow my lecturer's sample in txt file.

and how to convert it from an RGB image?

Answer (score 1):

That is most probably scientific notation:

```
3.7e+01 = 3.7 * 10**1
2.8e+03 = 2.8 * 10**3
```

etc. See here for the other way round:  [Display a decimal in scientific notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913532/display-a-decimal-in-scientific-notation)
and here for more explanation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation

If you put it into a variable, python will know it:

```
d = 3.7e6
print(d)
```

Output:

```
3700000.0
```

As for how to convert it to an image: it is a number - unless you have much more of them they won't make an image.

Most image formats I know of use triplets/quadruplets of ints (RGB/RGBA) or/and discrete values for widht*height.

You can transform the byte values into floats if you prefer to work with them that way, but my hedged guess is they only do  `value/255.0` to achive this.

Read more here: http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/user_guide/data_types.html

---

To convert from np array on ints to np array of floats:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([5,7,200,255])
print(arr)

arr = arr / 255.0
print (arr)
```

Output:

```
[  5   7 200 255]
[ 0.01960784  0.02745098  0.78431373  1.        ]
```