# How to use regex to format a number as 2.5k in a string to 2.5e3

Tags: python

I am parsing a spice file with python which contains string math expressions and I am converting the text file to a python script.

An example of a math expressions in the file is:

```
expr = 'k1 + 4.35k + 3.69meg*(pow(2.4u, 2*km2))'
```

I would like to find all the scaling factors in the expression and convert them to their exponent values:

```
scaling_factors = {
    'g'  : 'e9',
    'meg': 'e6',
    'k'  : 'e3',
    'm'  : 'e-3',
    'u'  : 'e-6',
    'n'  : 'e-9',
}
```

my wanted output would be like:

```
converted_expr = 'k1 + 4.35e3 + 3.69e6*(pow(2.4e-6, 2*km2))'
```

I tried this:

```
digits_re = r"([0-9]*\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+)k"
sample = 'k1 + 4.3k'
print(re.sub(digits_re, digits_re.replace('k', 'e3'), sample))
```

output:

```
k1 + \\de3
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: Thanks for giving us a clear idea of what you want to achieve, but have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: Have you at least tried to use `str.replace` ??

Comment: I started reading abour regular expressions very recently and so far my attempts have failed... I tried 
`import re
sample = 'k1 + 4.35k + 3.69meg*(pow(2.4u, 2*km2))'
print(re.findall("([0-9]*\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+)k", sample))
print(re.findall("([0-9]*\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+)meg", sample))`

output 
['4.35']
['3.69']

Comment: @IsslamAbdelhadi please add that attempt to your original post by editing it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a negative lookahead (`(?<=...)`) to make sure there's a number before the symbol(s), and a word boundary assertion (`\b`) to catch the "km2" case:

```
import re
expr = re.sub(r"(?<=\d)k\b", "e3", expr)
```

If you want to avoid doing this many times, there's a trick using a function as the replacement value:

```
def sn_replace(match):
    return scaling_factors[match.group(1)]

expr = re.sub(r"(?<=\d)(g|k|meg|m|u|n)\b", sn_replace, expr)
```

When the second argument to `re.sub` is a function, instead of replacing the match with a text, that function is called with the match object, and its return value is used as the replacement.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if there are any libraries that do something like this.

As one of the comments suggest you can use **str.replace**, but you will have to write your own *loop* and *If* conditions as you only want to replace the letters if they are in the right place.

I know this isn't giving you the answer straight away but it can guide to the right path.

Answer (score 0):

Written a bit quickly so may not be perfect, but something like this?

```
import re
scaling_factors = {
    'g'  : 'e9',
    'meg': 'e6',
    'k'  : 'e3',
    'm'  : 'e-3',
    'u'  : 'e-6',
    'n'  : 'e-9',
}

expr = 'k1 + 4.35k + 3.69meg*(pow(2.4u, 2*km2))'

for k,v in scaling_factors.items():
    ptrn=re.compile('\d('+k+')\D')
    expr=ptrn.sub(v,expr)
print(expr)
```

output:

```
k1 + 4.3e3+ 3.6e6(pow(2.e-6 2*km2))
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have the number as string you just need to replace:

```
for key in dictionary.iterkeys():
    address.replace(key, dictionary[key])
```

If you have the number in decimal values

```
from decimal import Decimal
'%.2E' % Decimal('40800000000.00000000000000')
# returns '4.08E+10'
```

[Display a decimal in scientific notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913532/display-a-decimal-in-scientific-notation)

Comment: You're assuming the input is a decimal value, but it's not