# Is it possible to print 1e-3 instead of 0.001 using print function in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to print the number 1e-3 instead of 0.001 in python. Do we have any option in print function to print it?

`number=0.001
print ('This is 0.6f ', number)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display a decimal in scientific notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913532/display-a-decimal-in-scientific-notation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly from the print function, but you can achieve this with:

```
import decimal
number = '0.001'
print ('%.3E' % decimal.Decimal(number))
```

Comment: Very nice solution. I got it