# How to print full integer like in python, in c++?

Tags: python, c++, algorithm

I have a code which runs and calculates a sequence of numbers and outputs it. When I run it on Python this is the number i get `89589789687112168422297691222737771124865819889385981395999564038551674847206437815235099730864284` 
But when I run the same code in c++ and output I get this `8.95898e+102`

I want the whole integer to be printed in c++. How can I achieve this?
It is a normal print statement in python : 
`print((2 ** q))` 
whereas in C++ I do this : 
`cout << pow(2, q)`

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/6913576/8150371

Comment: `pow` does not return an integer

Comment: `pow` returns a `double`, which is a floating point type, which [should not be used if you want precise calculations](https://floating-point-gui.de/basic/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    long double d{ 89589789687112168422297691222737771124865819889385981395999564038551674847206437815235099730864284.L };
    std::cout << std::fixed << d;
}
```

Precision of `long double` is not sufficient to represent the number accurately, though. If you need more you'd have to use a library for arbitrary precision like GMP.