# Python Maths Calculation on variables with scientific notation

Tags: python, python-2.7

How to use Python to handle scientific notation and perform calculations?
e.g:

```
a='1e+03'
b='1e+02'
```

How to sum a and b and get result of 1.1+03

Answer (score 1):

Python's built-in [`float`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#float) supports scientific notation:

```
a = '1e+03'
b = '1e+02'

res = float(a) + float(b)  # 1100.0
print int(res)             # 1100
```

Answer (score 1):

```
c = '{0:0.2e}'.format(float(a)+float(b))

In[10]: c
Out[10]: '1.10e+03'
```

Answer (score 0):

Is usage of float necessary ? I just used as it is and it printed out 1100.0

```
a = 1e+03

b = 1e+02

print(a+b)
```

This post might be helpful if you want the result exactly as 1.1+03 .
[Display a decimal in scientific notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913532/display-a-decimal-in-scientific-notation)

Comment: It's necessary (or advisable) if your input is a string, as in OP's example.

Comment: Ah ok. I did not notice the edited question. previous version of the post did not have quotes.