# The precision of Decimal library in python

Tags: python, decimal, precision

From the documentation page of [Decimal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html), I thought that once we use decimal to compute, it'll be a correct result without any floating error.

But when I try this equation

```
from decimal import Decimal, getcontext
getcontext().prec = 250

a = Decimal('6')
b = Decimal('500000')

b = a ** b
print('prec: ' + str(getcontext().prec) + ', ', end='')
print(b.ln() / a.ln())
```

It gives me different result!

[image]

I want to calculate the digit of `6**500000` in base-6 representation, so my expect result would be `int(b.ln() / a.ln()) + 1`, which should be 500001. However, when I set the prec to 250, it gives me the wrong result. How can I solve this?

Also, if I want to output the result without the scientific notation (i.e. `5E+5`), what should I do?

Comment: `decimal` is *adjustable* precision, not *infinite* precision. It says "correctly rounded decimal floating point arithmetic", not "unrounded real number arithmetic".

Comment: please don't upload images of text/code/data/errors when asking questions - instead, paste it in as a formatted code block. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Documentation clearly show the parameters of `getcontext()`

[image]

when you simply execute `getcontext()` it can show its built-in parameters.

```
Context(prec=28, rounding=ROUND_HALF_EVEN, Emin=-999999, Emax=999999, capitals=1, clamp=0, flags=[], traps=[InvalidOperation, DivisionByZero, Overflow])
```

When you can change `getcontext().prec = 250` then it can only overwrite `prec` value.

[image]

the main thing which can effect the result is `rounding parameter right after the prec`, It is built-in parameter `rounding=ROUND_HALF_EVEN`. I want to change this to `None` but it can show an error.

[image]

so it can clarify that no matter what we can do it must change even slightly because of `rounding` parameter.

Note: your result may also effect because of other built-in parameters.

Answer (score 2):

If you're after very precise or symbolic math and/or being bitten by IEEE 754 float aliasing, check out SymPy

```py
>>> from sympy import log, N
>>> expr = log(6**50000) / log(6)
>>> N(expr)
50000.0000000000
```

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for `Decimal.ln()` states:

> Return the natural (base e) logarithm of the operand. The result is correctly rounded using the ROUND_HALF_EVEN rounding mode.

When you changed the precision, more digits of the numbers were calculated and they are then rounded down instead of up. The number needs to be rounded because it is not necessarily within the specified precision, or even rational at all.

For outputting results in scientific notation, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913532/display-a-decimal-in-scientific-notation).