# How to distinquish between floats, ints and scientific notation

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I'm writing a custom json compresser. It is going to be reading numbers in all formats. How do I print the values of the json in the format, it is given, with json.load(). I would also want to preserve the type.

Example of a file it would have to read would be:

```
{"a":301, "b":301.0, "c":3.01E2, "d":"301", "e":"301.0", "f":"3.01E2"}
```

I would also want it to be able to distinquish between 1, 1.0 and true

When I do a basic for loop to print the values and their types with json.load(), it prints out

```
301 int
301.0 float
301.0 float
301 str
301.0 str
3.01E2 str
```

And yes, I understand that scientific notations are floats

Excpected output would be

```
301 int
301.0 float
3.01E2 float
301 str
301.0 str
3.01E2 str
```

Comment: It is unclear what you need, you're talking about encoding then loading (decoding) what do you need ?

Comment: Sorry about that, had a brain fart. I mean a loader.

Comment: So what is the expected output ? or expected thing to have ?

Comment: Expected out would be                
    301 int
    301.0 float
    3.01E2 float
    301 str
    301.0 str
    3.01E2 str

Comment: Python uses scientific notation for floats only if needed, for such a number it's not needed, so it doesn't

Comment: Yes, but the input contains the scientific notation, and I would like to havr it in the output

Comment: So see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913532/display-a-decimal-in-scientific-notation but I don't see way to know that this specific float was in scientific mode in the JSON, that 2 separates thins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So IIUC you want to keep the formatting of the json even if the value is given as float. I think the only way to do this is to change the type in your json i.e. adding quotes around float elements.

This can be done with regex:

```
import json
import re

data = """{"a":301, "b":301.0, "c":3.01E2, "d":"301", "e":"301.0", "f":"3.01E2", "g": true, "h":"hello"}"""

# the cricial part: enclosing float/int in quotes:
pattern = re.compile(r'(?<=:)\s*([+-]?\d+(?:\.\d*(?:E-?\d+)?)?)\b')
data_str = pattern.sub(r'"\1"', data)

val_dict = json.loads(data) # the values as normally read by the json module
type_dict = {k: type(v) for k,v in val_dict.items()} # their types
repr_dict = json.loads(data_str) # the representations (everything is a sting there)

# using Pandas for pretty formatting
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([val_dict, type_dict, repr_dict], index=["Value", "Type", "Repr."]).T
```

Output:

```
    Value             Type   Repr.
a     301    <class 'int'>     301
b   301.0  <class 'float'>   301.0
c   301.0  <class 'float'>  3.01E2
d     301    <class 'str'>     301
e   301.0    <class 'str'>   301.0
f  3.01E2    <class 'str'>  3.01E2
g    True   <class 'bool'>    True
h   hello    <class 'str'>   hello
```

So here the details of the regex:

- `([+-]?\d+(?:\.\d*(?:E-?\d+)?)?)` this is our matching group, consisting of:

  - `[+-]?` optional leading + or -
  - `\d+` one or more digits, followed by (optionally):
  - `(?:\.\d*(?:E-?\d+)?)?`: non capturing group made of

    - `\.` a dot
    - `\d*` zero or more digits
    - (optionally) an `E` with an (optional) minus `-` followed by one or more digits `\d+`
- `\b` specifie a word boundary (so that the match doesn't cut a series of digits)
- `(?<=:)` is a lookbehind, ensuring the expression is directly preceeded by `:` (we don't add quotes around existing strings)
- `\s*` any white character before the expression is ignored/removed

`\1` is a back reference to our (1st) group. So we replace the whole match with `"\1"`

Edit: slightly changed the regex to replace numbers directly following `:` and taking leading +/- into account

Comment: Would changing           (\d+(?:\.\d*(?:E-?\d+)?)?)      to            (?:\+?:\-\d+(?:\.\d*(?:E-?\d+)?)?)        make it also work work with -300 and +300 as inputs?

Comment: I edited my answer with a slightly more robust regex

Comment: Thanks for all the help. One thing i did notice was that if I have :4 or another number after a colon inside a string, it fails. I experimented a bit and found that this [https://regex101.com/r/nsP2zI/1](https://regex101.com/r/nsP2zI/1) seems to work pretty well at getting the keys with lists and special characters as values. However I couldn't figure out how to integrate this with your answer and have it choose the values, as I didn't quite understand how the lookbehind works

Comment: There are some redundancies in your regex, besides it matches more than the keys (some list elements as well). I think something like `(?:\{|,)\s*\"[^\"]*\":` would suffice. However lookbehinds must have fixed width in Python. So you cannot include this in it. You could check if the expression is followed by a comma by adding `\s*(?=,)` at the end of the pattern

Comment: Is there a way to count the commas(without backslashes) and check if they have a : after them? Because only checking the characters afterwards can lead to possible accisdent manipulation. That did fix the ":4", but now ":4," is broken. The only option that I could think of is somehow keeping a count of proceeding quotation marks

Comment: Regex is limited. If you want to exlude all possible errors, you'd be better off writing your own json parser that will read floats as strings

Comment: Welp, I just figuured out that i can replace the regex parsing with a "parse_float=str, parse_int=str" as json.loads' parametres. Thanks for the help though