# How to get entries of array with separated by string in one line?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have this data

```
[[ 2.696000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00]
 [ 2.577000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00]
 [ 0.000000e+00 -2.560096e+03  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00]
...
```

and want to print it as such, for each row

```
2.696000e+00 & 0.000000e+00 & 0.000000e+00 & 0.000000e+00 //
2.577000e+00 & 0.000000e+00 & 0.000000e+00 & 0.000000e+00 //
...
```

I have done is

```
for k in range(1):
for i in range(len(data[k])):
    print(data[k][i],'&')
    if i == len(data[k])-1:
        print(data[k][i],'//')
```

Which outputs

```
2.696 &
0.0 &
0.0 &
0.0 &
0.0 //
```

How to get rid of the new line between each entry of the row?

Comment: ``print(data[1][i],'&', end= " ")`` And you dont need ``for k in range(1):`` just replace ``k`` with zero in every line

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print without a newline or space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493386/how-to-print-without-a-newline-or-space)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `str.join` to join the numbers by `&` and then print `//` as last string:

```py
data = [
    [2.696000e00, 0.000000e00, 0.000000e00, 0.000000e00],
    [2.577000e00, 0.000000e00, 0.000000e00, 0.000000e00],
    [0.000000e00, -2.560096e03, 0.000000e00, 0.000000e00],
]

for row in data:
    print(' & '.join(map(str, row)), '//')
```

Prints:

```
2.696 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 //
2.577 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 //
0.0 & -2560.096 & 0.0 & 0.0 //
```

Comment: They appear to be using a 2d numpy array. Will this work for that?

Comment: @Barmar Yes, even with `data = np.array([ ... ])` it still works.

Comment: yep, thats exactly it, thx

Answer (score 1):

Just use the [join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) functions

```
' & '.join(map(lambda s: '%E'%s, [2.696000e00, 0.000000e00, 0.000000e00, 0.000000e00]))
```

Outputs

```
'2.696000E+00 & 0.000000E+00 & 0.000000E+00 & 0.000000E+00'
```

With the above approach, you can just do one loop and convert the array into a string with your preferred join character.

The map function is required to convert the decimal values to string. The lambda fn just formats the decimal into string using the E notation. A 'str' mapping would get rid of the 0s. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913532/display-a-decimal-in-scientific-notation) for details.

If you just want to stop print from spitting out newline, [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493386/how-to-print-without-a-newline-or-space)

Edit1: Updated code with map example

Comment: Their input is a 2d numpy array. Will this work with that?

Comment: Pls excuse me, it doesn't work. That was a rookie mistake from me. You'd need the map function like Andrej suggested. I'll update my answer