# How to write a number in scientific notation in Python keeping the mantissa as integer

Tags: python, notation, exponent

Suppose I have `x=3.141516` and `y=0.00129`. I need to format those numbers in scientific notation but the mantissa must not have decimal places. For example:

```
x = 3141516e-6
y = 129e-5
```

I have no idea how to solve this, since formatting in Python looks always assume decimal places.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913532/display-a-decimal-in-scientific-notation

Comment: you can use the format function to achieve this

Comment: @soyapencil No, scientific notation normally has one digit before the decimal. OP's looking for a form of *unnormalized* scientific notation, but I'm not sure what to call it exactly.

Comment: Ah yes, you're completely right. OP is not using normalized scientific notation -- the exponent + mantissa here do not have the usual values...

Comment: What format is the input? If float, [precision is complicated](/q/588004/4518341 "Is floating point math broken?"), so would you be OK with a fixed exponent and trailing zeroes? Otherwise, the input should probably be a string instead.

Comment: Er, I meant to say, a fixed mantissa width possibly with trailing zeroes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware how you can do it with `str.format` (to not have any decimal places), but you can construct the string manually (with help of [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) module):

```py
import decimal


def get_num(x):
    t = decimal.Decimal(str(x)).as_tuple()
    return f'{"-" if t.sign else ""}{"".join(map(str, t.digits))}e{t.exponent}'


print(get_num(3.141516))
print(get_num(0.00129))
print(get_num(-1.23))
```

Prints:

```
3141516e-6
129e-5
-123e-2
```